# Cannot restart Nginx after deleting letsencrypt certificate

Tags: nginx

I am getting connection refused while accessing the website.

while trying to resolve the issue i tried to restart the nginx server i got the below error message.

```
systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nginx[4400]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mobilitytechnews.net-0001/fullchain.p>
nginx[4400]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.


nginx.confi file



#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` has already told you exactly what's wrong:

```
nginx[4400]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mobilitytechnews.net-0001/fullchain.pem"
```

It means right what it says: somewhere in your configuration there is an `ssl_certificate` directive pointing to this file.

Also, I'm sure the `nginx` configuration you showed is incomplete, since `nginx` will never try to load certificate by itself, without corresponding directive in it's configuration.